# How to get highlighted text automatically in Android?

Tags: android, button, text, menu, click

I want to get a text automatically after highlighting it. But I don't want to click any button or menu..., only highlight the text.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will highlight a textview with a bg color

```
 EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
 BackgroundColorSpan span = new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFAABBCC);
 edit.getText().setSpan(span, 0, edit.getText().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: i think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188392/text-selection-listener-in-androidapi-level-7 (onselectionChanged method)

Comment: No, this isn't what I want to talk about. I have 2 EditText, one can input a text (etInput) and one cannot focus (etOuput). I will select some word in input text and after, it will appear in etOutput. I want to handle automatically. Sorry, I speak Eng not well :)